# PHP Default Timezone (or Date) with Custom Offset Using date()

Tags: php, date, timezone, offset, overriding

In ***PHP*** I am using `date_default_timezone_set` to set the default timezone.

Then whenever I use `date('m/d/y g:i A')` it gives me the correct time for that timezone regardless of location of client.

However,  I need to be able to set a **user-defined default timezone offset** when the page loads that is set in minutes.   so it could be anything from *-99999 to 0 to 99999.*

I can't figure out how to integrate the offset with the default timezone setting.

I've seen plenty of information on how to use *UTC* and *GMT* offsets,  but nothing about a custom default timezone offset (in minutes or seconds).

I'm hoping someone has some experience with this and can point me in the right direction.

Apparently this is impossible with PHP without defining a custom date wrapper and fetching and assigning the offset every time.

Does anyone else besides me think this should be included in PHP like..

`date_default_timezone_set($timezone, $optionalCustomOffset);`

I'm going to submit an RFC

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Pet0

Comment: How will your users define/set the timezone?  when they log in?  a config in the database?  detect browser setting somehow?     you can dynamically change the timezone setting with http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php **date_default_timezone_set()** .. that link will link to a list of acceptable time zone strings you can use.

Comment: I have already read that page.  The timezone is stored in a file, easily retreival by PHP or JS (via ajax).   Is there a way to set the timezone default offset that is not in hours and not a GMT or UTC offset using date_default_timezone_set?   If there is please post an answer because I was not able to figure it out.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to set a timezone other than in hours (or the occassional official time zone that is 30 minutes off).  If you want to calculate new dates offset in minutes in a non-standard way, you probably have to convert your times to unix timestamps (seconds since epoch) and consistently add/subtract the offsets before generating date strings for output.  If this is what you want, let me know and I'll give more details.

Comment: I saw a solution that looked like it might work using DateTime, but it would take too long to completely re-code that into the site.  So I am just creating a function to wrap the PHP date function and add the offset for now.  If someone provides an answer to this, I will still mark it correct.

Comment: @fbas Are you able to improve on the date function wrapper I posted as an answer below?

Comment: no. that is precisely what I was hinting at.  as long as you consistently use your function to generate date strings it will work.

Comment: Do you know anything about extending PHP (aka adding the custom offset to the date function itself?)

Comment: I foiund a better wway but I'm not sure if it will work.  Rename date function, then use functioon override to override it with my function.  Do you know if that will work with date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

Well, after I test this, if it works, I think that will be equivelant to the answer I was looking for so gonna have to mark my own answer correct unless anyone gonna come forward and show me up....

> (NOTE:  rename and override functions require that PECL APD be
>   installed.)

```
if (function_exist('__overridden__')) 
    { rename_function('__overridden__', 'dummy-override'); }
rename_function('date', 'date-native');
override_function('date', '$s ="l, F jS, Y, g:i:s A", $t = null', 'return izDate($s ="l, F jS, Y, g:i:s A", $t = null);');
rename_function("__overridden__", 'date-override');  
function izDate($s = 'l, F jS, Y, g:i:s A', $t = null) {
    $file = ('../timezone.config');
    $f = file_get_contents($file);
    $offset = getTzValue($f, 'offset');
    $time = $t === null ? time() : $t;
    $time += $offset ? (int) $offset : 0;
    return date-native($s, $time);
}
```

### END UPDATE

I didn't have a lot of time to wait for an answer on this one, so this is how I solved it.   If anyone has a better solution or can even help me write a better wrapper for this,  I will award the checkmark.

```
      function izDate($s, $t=null) {
          $file = ('../timezone.config');
          $f = file_get_contents($file);
          $offset = getTzValue($f, 'offset');
          $time = $t===null ? time() : $t;
          $time += $offset ? (int) $offset : 0;
          return date($s, $time);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

`getTimezoneOffset()` will subtract your time from GMT and return the number of minutes. So if you live in GMT-8, it will return 480. To put this into hours, divide by 60. Also, notice that the sign is the opposite of what you need -- it's calculating GMT's offset from your time zone, not your time zone's offset from GMT. To fix this, simply multiply by -1.

As far as geolocation, I've used MaxMind GeoIP on several projects and it works well, though I'm not sure if they provide timezone data. It's a service you pay for and they provide monthly updates to your database. They provide wrappers in several web languages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure you understood my question.   Please read my question again.  I'm looking to set the default timezone to a value that is offset in minutes.  There is no need to compare timezone offsets with GMT or UTC (as I said in my question).  I have the default timezone set already.  I just need to define a custom offset for the default timezone.